# Can't use laravel singleton inside Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom middleware where I want to use a singleton I use to pass php variables into my frontend, however I get the following error:

```
 ReflectionException (-1)
Class App\Http\Middleware\Javascript does not exist
```

My middleware:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;



class AuthAdmin
{


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user && $user['privileges'] > 2)
        {
            return $next($request);   
        }

        app(Javascript::class)->put(['showLoginModal' => true]);

        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

My ServiceProvider:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Helpers\Javascript;


class JavascriptServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Javascript::class, Javascript::class);
    }
}
```

composer dump-autoload didn't fix anything, I have been having problems where the Javascript Class is not found for some reason, any ideas or sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing Javascript class in your middleware. It's trying to find it in wrong namespace.

middleware:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use App\Helpers\Javascript;
```